# SymPy: Set specific latex name for symbol

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

Is it possible to set the LaTeX-name of a symbol explicitly and differently from it's SymPy-name? In an old issue on github I've found `x = sympy.symbols("x", latex=r"\alpha")`, but it seems that this doesn't work anymore. I think that the `latex` kwarg is deprecated, but I'm not sure. Printing `x` (even via `sympy.latex(x)` just return `x` instead of `α`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason for discontinuation (if it ever were an option) is the fact that you can reference a symbol with any python variable: variable names in python do not need to match the Symbol name.

```
>>> x=symbols('alpha')
>>> pprint(x)
α
```

It's only a common idiom to call Symbols by a variable the same as (or suggestive) of their name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I already knew that; the problem, however, is 1. that I have some rather ugly variable names (like $\widetilde{V}_S^R$, etc.) and 2. there is still a bug which won't let me use backslashes in index-names if want to lambdify an expression containing it. So having an additional LaTeX-name would be really nice.

Comment: ok -- not sure that there is any such option. What about just keeping a replacement dictionary for display purposes. So calculate with well-behaved symbol names and then print `expr.subs(replacement_dict)` instead of `expr`.

Comment: Yes, that's more less what I'm currently doing, but it starts getting really messy :S I've basically implemented a symbol-table mapping symbols to valid Python-names already, I really don't want to add another table for Latex-names. Would be better to just screw my old table, refactor all sympy-names into valid Python names and completely switch to the Latex-table... But honestly, I feel like this is really such a basic feature that Sympy misses, it's quite disappointing.